# Can't set customized header value with fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I want to send API KEY in the headers of my request. I use fetch method like this (I use react and its in shopify module) :

```
fetch("https://shopify.mysite.fr/shopify/articles/1", {
  method: "GET",
  mode: "cors",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "x-auth-token":"$2y$13$Kf0P46IM19qsdqk78SuB6CeuFfnonjsdfsdgsdhYvlSsf9uttNOgdjAQnZCz6y"
  }
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({ article: data });
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(console.log);
```

The problem is `"x-auth-token"` appeared in `"access-control-request-headers"` field. I just have the name but not the value (the key) and my API respond 401 ...

[request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOz8b.png)

What should I do to obtain `x-auth-token` in the api?

Comment: I guess you need to send "application/json" in  Content-Type header. `"Content-Type": "application/json"`. Also do you get any error in browser console? Did you enabled your api to accept your custom x-auth-token header?

Comment: https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/17056443-how-to-generate-a-shopify-api-token maybe you can look for official doc?

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard behaviour of the CORS enabled requests.
Before an actual call is made (GET with `x-auth-token` header) the browser is performing CORS preflight. This usually takes a form of additional OPTIONS request with your non-standard headers being sent in `access-control-request-headers` header, so that during an actual call server would know that it is safe to accept this non-standard header. Your 401 probably means that your API is not configured to accept cross origin calls or that it doesn't now your domain name and therefore prevents you from accessing it.